# Tag wiki edits do not show up in reputation tab on Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

The tag wiki edits do not show up in reputation tab on the Android App.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SAMSUNG-SM-G928A

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (G928AUCU3CPHA)